# Thread in rails for creating object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading

In my controller, I have :

```
@a = Myobject.new params
@b = Myobject.new params2
```

In the `models` folder, I have a class (no a model) :

```
class Myobject
 attr_accessor: :var1, :var2, :var3
 def initialize params
  # Some processes with SQL queries and classes variables.
  @var1 = result_of_a_sql_query
  @var2 = a_hash
  @var3 = params[:varpost]
 end
end
```

But it's slow.
I would like to launch this 2 object creations in parallel. (with thread or other)

I've tried :

```
t1 = Thread.new {@a = Myobject.new params}
@b = Myobject.new params2
t1.join
```

But I've got an error : `Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Myobject`

How can I launch this 2 commands in parallel ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to perform options on these objects immediately or is this a simple creation process? Also, which rails version are you using?

Comment: I don't think, I edited the class in my question. I think it's a simple creation process. I'm not in my work, I think rails 4 (but i'm certain >3.5)

Comment: rails version is 4.1.2

Comment: did you ever figure out how to get around this issue? im having the same one

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with complex object creation, but you need to get a prompt response back to your user, then it may be best to actually queue your object creation jobs where they can be processed on the system's own time rather than going through the whole thing during your action.

You might look at the [various background job gems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Background_Jobs) available to you. On the current application I am working with, updates are dropped into a Resque queue asynchronously and then pulled out and actions performed on the database as possible. This approach can work very well and is fairly standard in cloud environments.

If you need the data available on the front, that would not work as well but you could create simple proxy objects to return most of the data in a view, or simply perform async updates and maintain a front-end version of the data model too.

Comment: I would like just launch the first `@a = Myobject.new params` then wait where I want that job finishes. The two object creations are separate. I'm surprised there isn't another simply way. Why with simple thread, it doesn't work ?